# What mechanism is responsible for germinating in the right direction (root towards gravity)?

Tags: germination

Regardless of the initial seed orientation, the root always grows/sprouts/germinates "towards gravity" (see [picture](http://www.robsplants.com/images/seed/FilterSprouts2.jpg)), sometimes curving around in sharp 180°. What is the mechanism responsible for the **gravity sensing** and for the **growth adjustment**?

Comment: @WYSIWYG -the answer of the linked question indeed covers this question. The questions are however different. What to do?